# How to use dateutil in a nested list?

Tags: python, sorting, date, python-3.x

```
r = [['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2] , ['07-01-1988', 6], ['test', 4], ['12-12-2001', 5]]
```

Does anyone know how to use dateutil in a nested list?
I tried this without success:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
r = sorted(r, key=parse)
```

**error: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'**

I know there are other ways to sort dates but the thing I like of dateutils is that it recognizes dates without indicating the format. p.e. `21/09/1995` and `21-09-1995` is seen as dates.

Expected output:

```
r = [['test', 4], ['07-01-1988', 6], ['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2],  ['12-12-2001', 5]]
```

or

```
r = [['07-01-1988', 6], ['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2],  ['12-12-2001', 5], ['test', 4]]
```

Comment: `r = sorted(r, key=lambda values: parse(values[0]))`

Comment: @PeterWood, thanks Peter. It does a sort when I remove the sublist `['test', 4]` from above list. If not it gives this error: `ValueError: Unknown string format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

def my_parse(lis):
    try: 
        return parse(lis[0])
    except ValueError:
        return datetime(1, 1, 1)

print(sorted(r, key=my_parse))
```

Output:

```
[['test', 4], ['07-01-1988', 6], ['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2], ['12-12-2001', 5]]
```

You need to feed the first entry of your sub-lists to `parse()`. The entry `test` is not parseable and triggers a `ValueError`. Catch it and return a datetime object way outside of the range of dates you expect instead.

Use:

```
return datetime(9999, 1, 1)
```

if you want your entry with `test` as the last in the sorted result.

**EDIT**

If you want it to work with a flat **or** a nested list, you could check if the entry is a string or not:

```
r = ['test',  '21-09-1995 wednesday', '07-01-1988 tuesday'] 

from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

def my_parse(value):
    try: 
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return parse(value)
        else:
            return parse(value[0])
    except ValueError:
        return datetime(1, 1, 1)

print(sorted(r, key=my_parse))
```

This assumes that `value` is either an iterable containing strings or a string.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This resolves my question. Just to know, what do I have to change if a futur list is not a nested list? `return parse(lis[0])` --> `return parse(lis)` and `return datetime(1, 1, 1)` --> ?

Comment: you're right. It did not work when I added more text after the dates. ['test', '07-01-1988 tuesday', '21-09-1995 wednesday']

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dateutil at all, just change the dates to ints reversing so you start at the year:

```
r = [['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2] , ['07-01-1988', 6], ['test', 4], ['12-12-2001', 5]]

def srt(x):
    try:
        return int("".join(x[0].split("-")[::-1]))
    except ValueError:
        return 0
r.sort(key=srt)
```

Output:

```
[['test', 4], ['07-01-1988', 6], ['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2], ['12-12-2001', 5]]
```

If you don't mind having the text strings sorted to the end it is even simpler:

```
r.sort(key=lambda x: "".join(x[0].split("-")[::-1]))
```

That would give you:

```
['07-01-1988', 6], ['21-09-1995', 3], ['22-11-1995', 2], ['12-12-2001', 5], ['test', 4]]
```

For different format:

```
r = [['21-09-1995', 3], ['22/11/1995', 2] , ['07-01-1988', 6], ['test', 4], ['12-12-2001', 5]]

import  re

reg = re.compile("[\-/]")
r.sort(key=lambda x: "".join(reg.split(x[0])[::-1]))
```

Output:

```
[['07-01-1988', 6], ['21-09-1995', 3], ['22/11/1995', 2], ['12-12-2001', 5], ['test', 4]]
```

You can see there is quite a difference difference even using the regex:

```
r = [['21-09-1995', 3], ['22/11/1995', 2] , ['07-01-1988', 6], ['test', 4], ['12-12-2001', 5]] 
r.sort(key=my_parse)
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 185 µs per loop

In [5]: 

In [5]: %%timeit
r = [['21-09-1995', 3], ['22/11/1995', 2] , ['07-01-1988', 6], ['test', 4], ['12-12-2001', 5]] 
r.sort(key=lambda x: "".join(reg.split(x[0])[::-1]))
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.56 µs per loop

In [7]: %%timeit
r = [['21-09-1995', 3], ['22/11/1995', 2] , ['07-01-1988', 6], ['test', 4], ['12-12-2001', 5]] 
r.sort(key=regex_srt)
...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop
```

If you have a flat list and string like '07-01-1988 tuesday':

```
reg = re.compile("[\-/\s]")
r = ['test', '02/03/2015 test', '02/09/2016 test', '12/11/2011 test', '22/01/2015 test', '22/01/2010 test', '22/01/2013 test']
def srt(x):
    try:
        print(reg.split(x))
        return int("".join(reg.split(x)[:3][::-1]))
    except ValueError:
        return 0
r.sort(key=srt)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
['test', '22/01/2010 test', '12/11/2011 test', '22/01/2013 test', '22/01/2015 test', '02/03/2015 test', '02/09/2016 test']
```

Comment: OP: *I like of dateutils is that it recognizes dates without indicating the format. p.e. 21/09/1995 and 21-09-1995 is seen as dates.*

Comment: @MikeMüller, there are no other types in the input, this would also be a lot faster than trying to parse dates

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Thank you for your answer. I just checked your last function with this list `r
['test', '02/03/2015 test', '02/09/2016 test', '12/11/2011 test', '22/01/2015 test', '22/01/2010 test', '22/01/2013 test']` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, it will not work if one of the lines contains a date like this one: 2/4/2012 or this one: 02/4/2012